# Adobe Animate CC: Errors occurring in code written by program

Tags: javascript, animate-cc

I'm working on a project in Adobe Animate CC and coding in JavaScript.

When I preview the project (Ctrl-Enter), the browser throws two errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

I understand that this occurs when there is a bracket missing, but this code was generated by Animate, not by me.

Secondly:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: images is not defined
```

Referring to this line of code:

```
images = images||{};
```

Once again, generated by the program.

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Took a while for me to figure this out too. I assume this is HTML5 Canvas project in Animate CC.

The problem was that I had written *ActionScript* spesific types into the frames and not **EaselJS**.

Any code syntax error or AS3 specific definitions in the flash file causes this error when publishing into HTML5 Canvas.

You can propably get more specific error with some `try { } catch (e) { }` wrapper added into the generated code. Also, you can try to put the generated .js code into some javascript editor that shows invalid syntax/types.

Here you can find a complete documentation for EaselJS -programming:
http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/modules/EaselJS.html